# Incorrect syntax near '<' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the confusion, here's some more background information.

There is a modeltbl that needs to be pivoted on model_id. The following query updates the [MODEL_HISTORY_CREATE_VW]

What I'm trying to do is update the Table(MODEL_HISTORY) with the new columns being added. I have tried adding the columns, but that doesn't work. As many of you pointed out, i finally tried to update on SSMS.

```
CREATE VIEW [MODEL_HISTORY_CREATE_SQL_VW] AS 
SELECT SQL FROM (
select 'ALTER VIEW MODEL_HISTORY_CREATE_VW AS 
SELECT  [acctkey],[location_key],[snapshot_date]' sql, '0' as sort from dual  
union all
SELECT 
    case when model_output_score  = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_score  else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_score' else ' ' end   
    + case when model_output_decile = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_decile else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_decile_nat' else ' ' end  
    + case when model_output_div_decile = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_decile_div else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_decile_div' else ' ' end   
    + case when model_output_brx_decile = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_decile_brx else null end) as '  + model_prefix + '_decile_brx' else ' ' end 
    + case when model_output_segment = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_segment else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_segment' else ' ' end  
    + case when model_output_classification = 'Y' then ',' + model_aggregate +'(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_classification else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_classification' 
    --+ case when model_output_segment  = 'Y' then ', min(case when model_id = ''' + model_output_id +''' then model_output_segment  else null end) as ' + model_prefix + '_output_segment' else ' ' end
    else ' ' end    as sql, model_output_id as sort
FROM MetaTBL mdl   where model_active_status = 'Y'
union all  select   'FROM [ModelTBL]   
group by [acctkey], [location_key], [snapshot_date]' as sql, 'ZZZ' as sort from dual ) A
```

I've been trying to update a table and getting this error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As for your question, what sort of syntax is `= <prikey, varchar(MAX),>`? That is *not* valid T-SQL. I don't know where you've got that from, but it's not valid; simply put.

Comment: did you copy this straight from the docs? Pretty sure `<>` is just a place holder as in `<INSERT YOUR CODE HERE>`

Comment: Even the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) looks nothing like that, @Manakin , and certainly none of the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-a-simple-update-statement) do.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+M to fill in the [template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/template/replace-template-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15) in SSMS

Comment: You get this template in SSMS by right-click on table, Script Table As > UPDATE To > New Query Editor Window. But then you need to fill in the `<blanks>`

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the clarification I think Hans hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Yes, this is not my table, its written by someone else. I tried to type in the code, but it wont let me add it, so i had to paste the query.

Comment: I think i will have to spend sometime in following the suggestions here and see what would work. Thank you all for your comments. I'll post an update on how I fixed this.

Comment: 1) When you get problems with a generated command string, what really *is* the command string generated (you may need a space before "FROM")? 2) "from dual" sounds like Oracle, while you tagged it sql-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value that you want to put for the column at the right side of the = instead of the values between < >.

For example, let's say you want to set the following arbitrary values in the test_table table:

```
prikey = '1'
location_key = '2'
snapshot_date = 20101102000000
ABC_XX_SEGMENT = 'XX'
ABC_YYY_scr = 'YYY scr'
ABC_YYY_dec_brx = 'YYY dec'
```

you would use the following query:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET
    prikey = '1',
    location_key = '2',
    snapshot_date = 20101102000000,
    ABC_XX_SEGMENT = 'XX',
    ABC_YYY_scr = 'YYY scr',
    ABC_YYY_dec_brx = 'YYY dec';
```

Normally, such an update would be a bad idea without using a WHERE clause, as it would update all rows with these values. For example, if you want to update the row with the prikey set at 1 using the following query:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET
    location_key = '2',
    snapshot_date = 20101102000000,
    ABC_XX_SEGMENT = 'XX',
    ABC_YYY_scr = 'YYY scr',
    ABC_YYY_dec_brx = 'YYY dec'
WHERE prikey = '1';
```